# Position my movieclips Flash/Air on the screen

Tags: flash, air

How can I place my air files in the specific location on the monitor.
I have 3 movieclips at my project.
Let's say I want movieclip "A" to be at left bottom corner at my monitor.
movieclip "B" center the monitor.
movieclip "C" top right corner of the monitor.
The air app will be custom window(transparent)
I understand there's a lot different sizes of monitors available.
But how my air app will align the movieclips to the monitors?
I will really appreciate if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

In AIR, there are `Capabilities.screenResolutionX` and `Capabilities.screenResolutionY`. These give screen size in pixels (not sure how it will works with multiple monitors, but with single monitor it's OK).